# Node custom property exposed as extra field

Tags: entities

I'm trying to add custom property to node bundle, my code so far:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $properties = &$info['node']['bundles']['program']['properties'];

  $properties['last_episode_date'] = array(
    'label' => t("Last episode date"),
    'type' => 'date',
    'computed' => TRUE,
    'entity views field' => TRUE,
    'metadata controller class' => 'EntityDefaultMetadataController',
    'extra fields controller class' => 'EntityDefaultExtraFieldsController',
    'getter callback' => 'mymodule_last_episode_date_getter',
    'description' => t("Date of the last episode."),
  );
  return $info;
}

/**
 * last_episode_date property getter.
 */
function mymodule_last_episode_date_getter($data, array $options, $name, $type, $info) {
  return REQUEST_TIME;
}
```

The goal is to have this property available in views and in node as extra field - in views it is available, but I cannot make it to work as extra field. Anything is missing/is wrong? Documentation on this is kind of lacking :( .

Comment: That sound like a crazy way to create simple, stupid field using field UI :)
btw. I believe you must alter node_form and add this property as a field, add table to store value and alter node load and node view to load and prepare to display data.

Comment: I have to agree with @zaporylie. Is there a reason you aren't just adding this field through the UI?

Comment: Why is this crazy? Just views integration and extra field at the same time with a simple code. :) Notice that this is not a typical field - this is computed field. I would argue that installing computed field module would be even more crazy for a simple goal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at Entity module's hook_field_extra_fields() implementation:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_extra_fields().
 */
function entity_field_extra_fields() {
  // Invoke specified controllers for entity types provided by the CRUD API.
  $items = array();
  foreach (entity_crud_get_info() as $type => $info) { ... }
  return $items;
}
```

It only looks for entity types provided by the CRUD API -- in other words, entities whose controllers inherit from EntityAPIControllerInterface. Node entities use NodeController.

You can still do this conventionally, outside of Entity API -- implement hook_node_view() to insert your pseudo-field in $node['content'], then implement hook_field_extra_fields() to expose that pseudo-field to the node's "Manage display" tab.

Comment: So "extra fields controller class" in the end works only for custom entities? Wouldn't expect this :( , that would be a great feature if we could add properties that way to node.